# Edit textfile with python re

Tags: python, regex

I have a large textfile (>200mb) with 70k rows. Now I want to find some special text in each row an place it again at the end of each row (separated with a $-symbol). N++ and Regex works, but is a bit slow, so I want try it with python.

With the code I'll get a "TypeError: must be str, not list" for fn.write(text+run+"\n")

```
import re

with open('Testfile.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        text = line.replace("\n","$")
        run = re.findall(r'Typ: (.*?);', line) or "0"
        print(text+run)

        with open ("NEWTest.txt", mode="w") as fn:
            fn.write(text+run+"\n")
```

Does anyone know the error and also knows if there is an even faster way (code)?

Comment: You should have posted the error and highlighted the line number. Beside try `print(type(line))` check if it is `str`

Comment: I edit my post. print(type(line)) = each line is a str.

Comment: so here. `text = line.replace("\n","$")` or `run = re.findall(r'Typ: (.*?);', line) or "0"` is returning a list. please add a print statement for both `text` and `run` and check.

Comment: print text and run separately works fine, print text+run give's an error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: As highlighted by @MatsLindh Use `fn.write(text + ''.join(run) + "\n")` inplace of `fn.write(text+run+"\n")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall` returns a list of strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) - i.e. all matches found in the text given to it.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'Typ: (.*?);', 'Typ: foobar;')
['foobar']
```

To include it again at the end, you can join all the matches together:

```
 fn.write(text + ''.join(run) + "\n")
```

If you only want one match, you can use `re.search` instead:

```
>>> re.search(r'Typ: (.*?);', 'Typ: foobar;').group(1)
'foobar'
```

It works with your example:

```
>>> re.search(r'Typ: (.*?);', 'Typ: Mehrfamilienhaus;').group(1)
'Mehrfamilienhaus'
```

But since `re.search` will give `None` if there isn't a match, you can check that you get a proper match before attempting to retrieve the `group` (as you do in your `findall` above):

```
result = re.search(r'Typ: (.*?);', 'Typ: Mehrfamilienhaus;')
run = result.group(1) if result else '0'
```

Comment: I tried with search and print and it don't work: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. If I leave the group statement my Output shows like: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(117, 139), match='Typ: Mehrfamilienhaus;'>. But I only want to get "Mehrfamilienhaus".

Comment: In that case it sounds like you also have lines that doesn't match the regex. The one you've included gives a patch. I've updated the answer with how to check that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import re

with open('Testfile.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        text = line.replace("\n","$")
        run = re.findall(r'Typ: (.*?);', line) or "0"


        with open ("NEWTest.txt", mode="w") as fn:
            fn.write(text + ''.join(run) + "\n")
```

**Or**

```
with open('Testfile.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        text = line.replace("\n","$")
        run = re.search(r'Typ: (.*?);', line) or "0"


        with open ("NEWTest.txt", mode="w") as fn:
            fn.write(text + run + "\n")
```

Comment: Both scripts don't work. 1. error is TypeError: must be str, not list. And 2. error is TypeError: must be str, not _sre.SRE_Match

Comment: @JuliGoe Can try the answer now.

Comment: Now the first one works fine. Thanks. I have also found another mistake: I have to use mode "a" instead of "w".